# Arrange the dataframe in increasing or decreasing order based on specific group/id in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe given as such:

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd


#Create dataset
data = {'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A','A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
               'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',
               'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C',
               'D', 'D', 'D', 'D',
               'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E','E', 'E', 'E','E'],
        'cycle': [1,2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,
                   1,2, 3,4,5,6,
                   1,2, 3, 4, 5,6,
                  1,2, 3, 4,
                  1,2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,],
        'Salary': [7, 7, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
                   4, 4, 4,4,5,6,
                   8,9,10,11,12,13,
                   8,9,10,11,
                   7, 7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,],
        'Children': ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 
                     'No','Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes',
                     'Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes',
                      'No',  'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',],
        'Days': [123, 128, 66, 66, 120, 141, 52,96, 120, 141, 52,
                 96, 120,120, 141, 52,96,
                 15,123, 128, 66, 120, 141,
                 141,123, 128, 66,
                 123, 128, 66, 123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 52,],
        }

#Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("df = \n", df)
```

The above dataframe looks as such:

[image]

Here,

id 'A' as 11 cycle

id 'B' as 6 cycle

id 'C' as 6 cycle

id 'D' as 4 cycle

id 'E' as 9 cycle

I need to regroup the dataframe based on following two cases:

**Case 1: Increasing order of the cycle**

The datafrmae needs to be arraged in the increasing order of the cycle.

i.e. D(4 cycle) comes first, then B(6 cycle), C(6 cycle), E(9 cycle), A(11 cycle)

The dataframe need to look as such:

[image]

**Case 2: Decreasing order of the cycle**

The datafrmae needs to be arraged in the decreasing order of the cycle.

i.e. A(11 cycle) comes first, then E(9 cycle), B(6 cycle), C(6 cycle), D(4 cycle)

The dataframe need to look as such:

[image]

In both the cases, id 'B' and 'C' has 6 cycle. So it is immaterial which will come first amongst 'B' and 'C'.

Also, the index number dosen't change in the original and regrouped cases.

Can somebody please let me know hot to achieve this task in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.transform('size')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) as the sorting value:

Either using a temporary column:

```
(df.assign(size=df.groupby('id')['cycle'].transform('size'))
   .sort_values(by=['size', 'id'], kind='stable',
               # ascending=False # uncomment for descending order
               )
   .drop(columns='size')
)
```

Or, passing as `key` to [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df.sort_values(by='id', key=lambda x: df.groupby(x)['cycle'].transform('size'),
               kind='stable')
```

Output:

```
   id  cycle  Salary Children  Days
23  D      1       8      Yes   141
24  D      2       9       No   123
25  D      3      10      Yes   128
26  D      4      11      Yes    66
11  B      1       4      Yes    96
12  B      2       4      Yes   120
13  B      3       4       No   120
14  B      4       4      Yes   141
15  B      5       5      Yes    52
16  B      6       6      Yes    96
17  C      1       8       No    15
18  C      2       9      Yes   123
19  C      3      10      Yes   128
20  C      4      11       No    66
21  C      5      12       No   120
22  C      6      13      Yes   141
27  E      1       7       No   123
28  E      2       7      Yes   128
29  E      3       9       No    66
30  E      4      10       No   123
31  E      5      11      Yes   128
32  E      6      12      Yes    66
33  E      7      13      Yes   120
34  E      8      14      Yes   141
35  E      9      15       No    52
0   A      1       7       No   123
1   A      2       7      Yes   128
2   A      3       7      Yes    66
3   A      4       8      Yes    66
4   A      5       9      Yes   120
5   A      6      10       No   141
6   A      7      11       No    52
7   A      8      12      Yes    96
8   A      9      13      Yes   120
9   A     10      14      Yes   141
10  A     11      15       No    52
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mozway for your valuable suggestions. How do I ensre that the index number starts from '0' in the new dataframe ?

Comment: add `ignore_index=True` in `sort_values`

Answer (score 1):

```
col1=df.groupby("id").cycle.transform("max")
case1=df.assign(col1=col1).sort_values(['col1','id'])
case1

case2=df.assign(col1=col1).sort_values(['col1','id'],ascending=False)
case2
```